# Can't access the enhanced session menu after setting it for the first time

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, shared-folders

I am trying to get the "Connect to" prompt in Hyper-V after I have set some shared folders.
Image: [Connect to VM prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/learn-more/media/hyperv-vmconnect-displayconfig.png).

[Current shared folders are mapped with tsclient.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlnlL.png) The mapping was done with that prompt.

I don't get the prompt anymore when I connect or enable enhanced session but I need to share more folders from the host machine. As far as I know that is the only way to configure shared resources with the host machine.

I have tried disabling the enhanced session ([2 checkmarks in settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/learn-more/media/hyper-v-settings-userenhancedsessionmode.png)), restarting the host pc, and enabling e.s. back and I still don't get it.

Virtual machine is Gen 1.
Host machine is win 11 and win 10 in virtual env.

The virtual environment has disabled the network adapter for a reason.

Comment: What you want needs a Generation 2 machine. Is your VM Generation 2?

Comment: I am using Gen 1. But I have been able to set shared folders with it.

Comment: You can map folders in the standard NET USE fashion and that works with Generation 1.

Comment: I am trying to avoid it since I will use it on a laptop, connected to public networks.

I guess I can set it up so that only my VM has access to it. Most guides just set the access to the shared folder to everyone read/write.

Comment: Standard folder mapping works on a laptop.  I use that here.

Answer (score 1):

In Hyper-V, shared folders and other enhanced concepts (for example, resize the VM window size) require a Generation 2 virtual machine.

For a Generation 1 virtual machine, standard folder mapping between machines and host works fine.

From Windows to Windows:  Map Folder Options or NET USE works fine.

From Linux to Windows, Linux File App:  SMB://192.168.x.y/folder and authenticate.  This works fine.

From Windows to Linux:  Install Samba on Linux. This works fine as well but takes some Samba setup.

[Samba Tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#2-installing-samba)

If the OS you have or another version of it can be installed as a Generation 2 machine, you can do that and take advantage of Generation 2 features.